# flutter check if user id exists in cloud firestore collection

Tags: forms, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, exists

I am trying to get the user id and check if exists in flutter using firestore but I don't get the correct result.

```
 handlesearch() {

final form = formkey.currentState;

    final Future<QuerySnapshot> result =  Firestore.instance
        .collection('users')
        .where('userid', isEqualTo: form)
        .getDocuments();

    setState(() {

      searchresult = result;

    });


 buildsearch() {


    return AppBar(
      title: Container(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Form(
              key: formkey,
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: searchcontroller,
                onSaved: (val) => userid = val,
                // onFieldSubmitted: handlesearch,
              ),

            ),
            RaisedButton(
              child: Text('submit'),
              onPressed: handlesearch,
            )
          ],



 @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {


Scaffold(

      appBar:buildsearch(),

      body:
return FutureBuilder(

        future: searchresult,
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {

          if(snapshot.hasData){
            return buildexists();
          }
            return builddoesntexists();

        }
        );
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why or how you would use `formkey.currentState` to get the user id.

Instead, you might want to use the form controller : `searchcontroller.text`

But since you're saving it in a custom variable, you could also use it : `userid`

N.B :  in your onSaved function, be sure to call setState to rebuild with the updated value :

```
onSaved: (val) => setState(() => userid = val);
```